# I can't add Firebase admin sdk to the project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to delete firebase user with Uid but I can't add firebase admin sdk to the project.

I get this error:
http:\i.ibb.co/nMY4R1m/image.png

my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'
    implementation 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.0.0'
}
```

I don't have any idea that what is the problem with my code

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK is designed for use in server environments. You can't add it to an Android app.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your prompt reply.